# How to remove WebStorm sass-lint error "Unknown pseudo selector 'ng-deep'"

Tags: css, angular, angular-components, scss-lint

Angular 2+ with scss and ::ng-deep in WebStorm highlights this selector with text "Unknown pseudo selector 'ng-deep'"

I tried something like:

```
selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown: true
  ignorePseudoClasses: ng-deep

or

selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown: false
```

None of this works.

How to set exception in scss-lint.yml for this pseudo-selectors?

Comment: Does that help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206340199-Unknown-pseudo-selector-how-to-ignore-

Comment: @Tonio You should use that in an answer quoting the relevant text.

Comment: After WebStorm update this issue no longer appears

Answer (score 20, accepted):

::ng-deep is pseudo element, not pseudo class.
This is equivalent in my .stylelintrc

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [true, {
      "ignorePseudoElements": ["ng-deep"]
    }]
  }
}
```

Also you need to uncheck Settings -> Inspections -> CSS -> Invalid Elements -> Invalid CSS pseudo selector

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 4.x you can use `/deep/` instead of `::ng-deep`.

**UPD 14.05.2018**

Quote from angular.io:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

So basically you *should not use* any of them because Angular team will stop supporting this feature.

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated from 4.3 
more info here - https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/

Comment: If needed then you should use ::ng-deep but yes.. they are all to be deprecated :)